# Routing error - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I could not fix this in Rails 3.2.12, maybe I am missing something.

**config/routes.rb**

```
get "home/index"
root :to => "home#index"
devise_for :users, :only => :omniauth_callbacks
match 'users/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
match '/auth/:provider/signout' => 'authentications#signout'
```

**app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb**

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

**app/models/authentication.rb**

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

I think it should work with my current knowledge, but there is something that I miss.

My kind question would be to tell what is wrong, please.

**Rounting Error**

`uninitialized constant AuthenticationsController`

This is a message that shows up at `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/signout`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Rails requires the file name to match the class name. Therefore you should rename `app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb`.

Comment: oh. thank you @alfonso. I created controller in this way `rails g controller authentication` so file was named to `authentication_controller.rb` by itself, maybe I changed class name. Thank you very much for responding to such a known-by-most question.

Comment: @Davit Tip: You should always use plural while generating controllers.

Comment: Thank you! Been searching for the answer to this one for far too long.

Answer (score 5):

Though this question has been answered, I found another case where I was getting this error and wanted to document it here for posterity.

If you have two similar routes defined in your routes.rb file without the corresponding controllers you will get the uninitialized constant error.

Steps to reproduce:

```
rails generate scaffold foobar name:string
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

add **resources :foobars** to routes.rb to a new scope (note: the foobars resource was already automatically added to the top of your routes.rb during scaffold generation) like this:

```
  resources :foobars

  ########################################
  # SUPER
  ########################################

  constraints host: ENV['SUPER_HOST'] do
    scope module: :super do
      resources :foobars
      get '/' => 'super#index'

    end
  end
```

Now, move **/app/views/foobars** to **/app/views/super/foobars**
and, move **/app/controllers/foobars_controller.rb** to **/app/controllers/super/foobars_controller.rb**
Make sure foobars_controller.rb is in the Super module:

```
class Super::FoobarsController < ApplicationController
```

Now go to your.dev.server/foobars/
You should get this error:
Routing Error uninitialized constant FoobarsController

Now, remove **resources :foobars** from beginning of routes.rb
It should work now!

It took me awhile to figure out why I was getting this error, and I didn't realize that generating the scaffold adds an entry in routes.rb

Comment: https://github.com/swilson223/ParkingAppDevelopment Is the git hub to the source code if you want to see it in full context

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't answer your specific question, I received the failure with the following in my routes.rb

```
resources :republishes  do
    post '/attempt_all', :to => 'republishes/#attempt_all' . . .
```

which I changed to

```
resources :republishes  do
    post '/attempt_all', :to => 'republishes#attempt_all' . . .
```

Removing the slash fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Since I'd scaffold the module, it was already had initiated routes for the controller and I was defining it twice. So by removing one of the duplicate resource routes resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you've created your model for the controller in question.