# uninitialized constant Users::Auth::Instagram::CallbackController -- Not sure which part of configuration is incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using *devise* and started to implement *omniauth-instagram.*  However, I keep getting an error that reads:

`uninitialized constant Users::Auth::Instagram::CallbackController`

I'm not sure which part of my configuration is incorrect so I've included some excerpts from my routes.db , omniauth_callbacks_controllers.rb, and devise.rb for reference.

Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

routes.db 
`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/auth/instagram/callbacks" }`

/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controllers.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def instagram

      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.find_for_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_users)

      if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Instagram") if is_navigational_format?
      else
        session["devise.instagram_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end

  end

end
```

devise.rb
`config.omniauth_path_prefix = 'users/auth/instagram/callbacks'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized my naming convention was incorrect!

With the help of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845491/routing-error-uninitialized-constant), I realized that my file name was not matching the class name my routes and paths were referring to.

For example, routes.rb and devise.rb were both referring to path:
`"users/auth/instagram/callbacks"`

My classes file name before and after:
`users/auth/instagram/omniauth_callbacks_controllers.rb`
`users/auth/instagram/callbacks_controllers.rb`

It's also important to note that the classname within my `callbacks_controllers.rb` also, appropriately, reflect the path of the file:
`class Users::Auth::Instagram::CallbacksController`

Answer (score 0):

If you see your devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth_path_prefix = 'users/auth/instagram/callbacks'
```

and your routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/auth/instagram/callbacks" }
```

both points to `Users::Auth::Instagram::CallbacksController`

while you have defined:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

inside **/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controllers.rb**

this should be: **/controllers/users/auth/instagram/callbacks_controllers.rb**

and your class should change to:

```
class Users::Auth::Instagram::CallbackController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

Or remove `/auth` from both(routes.rb and devise.rb) the places and see if it works?

Comment: Hrm... I tried both your suggestions above and still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: is there something else I should be checking out?  When I take my browser to `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/instagram/callbacks` I get a Routing Error that **No route matches [GET] 'users/auth/instagram/callbacks'** Even though when I scroll down I see this route does exist.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice to mention that you need to rename your `/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controllers.rb` to `/controllers/users/auth/instagram/callbacks_controllers.rb`. I hope you've got this working anyways. I'll update in answer.