# Ruby on Rails : uninitialized constant AdminController

Tags: ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

> Routing Error ! uninitialized constant AdminController

This appears to me when trying to go to

```
localhost:3000/admin
```

I have been searching a lot , but still stuck!

Rails 4.2.4

Ruby 2.2.3

Activeadmin 1.0.0 pre2

My Gem file :`5dPDVf` http://ideone.com/5dPDVf

My routes.rb File : `dF6EFT`http://ideone.com/dF6EFT

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Be good if you post the class definition and location of AdminController, it may be a pluralisation issue: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845491/routing-error-uninitialized-constant

Comment: Thnx 4 your reply
1-/myapp/app/admin/dashbored.rb->http://ideone.com/T3p6Za
2-/myapp/config/intializers/active_admin.rb->http://ideone.com/0pfHHe
3-/myapp/config/environment/production.rb->http://ideone.com/OQHCQC
4-/myapp/config/environment/development.rb->http://ideone.com/NY1qda
5-/myapp/config/environment/test.rb->http://ideone.com/fKnRjm
6-/myapp/config/application.rb->http://ideone.com/zS7sSP
7-/myapp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb-> http://ideone.com/6DfMEU
8-/myapp/app/models/admin_user.rb->http://ideone.com/LCLOHD
9-/myapp/app/admin/admin_user.rb->http://ideone.com/qpCgtL

Comment: Please Note that I am a very new Rails developer , So if anything isn't clear for you , it's my fault and your help is appreciable for me . 
Thanks Tim

Comment: No problem Karim, I was just going through a review queue , I see someone had gotten to you. Good luck.

Comment: Not yet , Still have problem and stuck :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create an AdminsController class like this:

in `app/controllers/admins_controller.rb`

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def index      
  end 
end
```

You might want to read [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

You might have it defined as AdminsController (plural) so you might need to adjust your routes to this instead of creating an `AdminsController` class.

The controller name should be plural (this is a naming convention in Rails).

`routes.rb`

```
resources :admins
```

You'll also need a view file in`app/views/admins/` called `index.html.erb`

and then visit `http://localhost:3000/admins`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for replay , 
I have created admin_controller.rb 
but Is that anything to put instead of this dots (...) between declaration for call and it's end ??
- When I create it and erase these dots 
I opened by routes.rb and add resources :admins 
It still the same 
and I also try resources :admin (Singular) it also not working !

Comment: see edit about the controller name being plural - the ... can be replaced by actions like `def index end` (again - see edit in my answer also recommend reading the Action Controller Overview Rails Guide.

Comment: Now , I got something new                                         -> 
Template is missing
"Missing template admins/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/karim/myapp/app/views" * "/home/karim/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views" * "/home/karim/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f7483e3b8fcd/app/views" * "/home/karim/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"

Comment: You need to create a view file: `app/views/admins/index.html.erb`

Comment: Umm,It works!but not as excepted Sir please,I have my app folders structure look like admin,assets,controllers,helpers,mailers,models,views
I opened the views folder as u said,and create new folder admins/index.html.erb but , we I load localhost:3000/admins -> it appears blank page for me It is obviously because of this new page that I create and when running localhost:3000/admins/admin_users->it expect to show admins but it gives"The action 'show' could not be found for AdminsController".I am following some Udemy course tutorials and he didn't face this due to rails,activeadmin diff. versions

Comment: you'll need to create a show action in your AdminsController and a view that corresponds with it. You can add HTML to the `index.html.erb` file if you want to display something on that page.

Comment: Ummm Thanks for you Time

Answer (score -1):

Did you run rails generate active_admin:install ?

Comment: Thanks Eduardo for Replay , 
Yes I did this .

Answer (score -1):

when you get this exception at that time **just restart your server** and that works for me

in local you did

`rails s`

now the server is on so now you have to exit from the started server

now run again `rails s` then

**Hurrrayyy.!!!**
it working fine